# Recording an excel macro using a workbook the has a changing name

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

In Excel 2010, I have a requirement after someone clicks move or copy to a new workbook, to then run the following statement on the new workbook:

```
Sub CSAColorFormattingSSRS2008()
      ActiveWorkbook.Colors = Workbooks("Book4").Colors
End Sub
```

The problem is that the "Book4" is the previous workbook the sheet came from, but this workbook name can change. Is there a way to do this with a changing workbook name that you are copying from? I am trying to just create a button to run this macro for everyone, but all the past book names are always different.

Comment: can you just create a procedure that sets the colors you want, then call that for the `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: This is actually for multiple different workbooks containing different columns and data. What I am actually doing is using SSRS 2008 and trying to fix the color bug caused by copying over sheets to another workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, where the button does the copy operation for them and then sets the colors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySetColor()
Dim strWkb As String, strSheet As String
strWkb = ThisWorkbook.Name
strSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

'get Workbook name to copy to -> ensure that only 2 workbooks are open, this and the one you want to copy to
Dim wkb As Workbook, wkbCopyTo As Workbook

For Each wkb In Workbooks

    If wkb.Name <> strWkb Then

        Set wkbCopyTo = wkb
        Exit For

    End If

Next

Sheets(strSheet).Copy Before:=wkbCopyTo.Sheets(1)

CSAColorFormattingSSRS2008 strWkb

End Sub

Sub CSAColorFormattingSSRS2008(strName As String)

      ActiveWorkbook.Colors = Workbooks(strName).Colors

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to actually manually right click the sheet tab and do move or copy so I can select what new workbook I want it in. When I run this it copies the sheet to a new workbook, but I cant pick which one. Is it possible to do this and pick what workbook you want this copied to? The workbook it's copied to is always opened alongside the other workbook, yet again the workbook can be names anything.

Comment: @mameesh, see my edit. If you can ensure that the only 2 workbooks that are open are the one copying from and to, it will work great. I didn't put this in the code, but you could do a check with `Workbooks.Count` and use a message box to tell the user to close all other workbooks. I realize this is ugly, but if you have more than 1 other workbook open, it becomes harder. You could probably use your creativity to find a way to let the user choose which workbook if there is more than one... like with a list box on a form or something.